# How can I make Wordpress work with a Symfony app?

Tags: wp-admin, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, apache

Basically, I have a website built that has two components. One component is the the WordPress part, under "/". And the second component is a Symfony app under "/foo". How can I make Word-press ignore the "/foo" route and redirect that to the Symfony app?

I assume that I have to use an .htaccess file to accomplish (website will run on Apache) this, but I am not too well-versed in the syntax.

Helpful Info:

- Wordpress Version 4.8 Symfony Version 3.3 Apache 2.4

Comment: Is my assumption right that you don't have an index.php file in your /foo directory? Maybe you add one redirecting to to app.php and it should work out of the box without any htaccess or other modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Update your .htaccess in WordPress root folder with below code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo
RewriteRule ^/foo/app\.php$ - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: while probably correct it is not a great idea to do it inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block as it might be overwritten when wordpress regenerates the htaccess rules.

Comment: It works in that it redirects to the proper directory. But it doesn't execute web/app.php . It just displays the content of the directory (the entire source code of the web app).